# Average last 5 values in 2D range in Excel

Tags: excel

I've seen many solutions to get the average of the last 5 values in either a column or a row (see: [[link 1](https://exceljet.net/formula/average-last-5-values-in-columns)], [[link 2](https://exceljet.net/formula/average-last-5-values)] & [[link 3](https://superuser.com/questions/1061446/how-do-i-calculate-average-of-last-10-values-from-a-row-containing-blanks)]). However, the same approach cannot be used, in my case, a 2D range with blanks.

Example:
[image]

Each week I would like to see what the average value is of the last 5 non-blank cells. My definition of last 5 is accordingly:

- Only non-blank cells in the same row or rows above "count" (relative to the cell in "Average Last 5" column
- The last column is the most "recent value". Thus in chronological order: column 1 until 5

Thus for example for week 9, the average of the last 5 values are week 7/day 1, week 8/day 3, week 8/day 5, week 9/day 1 and week 10/day 4.

Right now, this is calculated by selecting the last 5 manually. But I would like to automate this.

I've included some examples in the image above. So the marked cells belong to the average last 5 used in the corresponding colored cell.

If it is not clear, please ask.

Comment: Unclear... say the table is completely filled, no empties ......... do you want the last 5 values in the last row or the last five values in the last column??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I've modified the question. Hope this makes it clear. So basically the columns are chronological aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function.

Put this code in a module attached to the workbook.

```
Function LastFive(rng As Range, cnt As Long)
Dim rngArr As Variant
Dim outArr As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim aCnt As Long
rngArr = rng.Value
ReDim outArr(1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(rng), cnt))
aCnt = 1
For i = UBound(rngArr, 1) To LBound(rngArr, 1) Step -1
    For j = UBound(rngArr, 2) To LBound(rngArr, 2) Step -1
        If Not IsEmpty(rngArr(i, j)) Then
            If IsNumeric(rngArr(i, j)) And aCnt <= cnt Then
                outArr(aCnt) = rngArr(i, j)
                aCnt = aCnt + 1
                If aCnt > cnt Then
                    LastFive = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(outArr)
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i
LastFive = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(outArr)


End Function
```

Then in The first cell you would use the formula:

```
=LastFive($B$2:F2,5)
```

Then drag down.  Not that the first cell is absolute and the last is not.

The `5` is the number of numbers desired in the average.  You can change that if desired to include more or less.

[image]